# Use class variable in filter method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I am using AngularJS and Typescript. The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

- In the Typescript controller class I have an array of loans, each loan with a currency object.
- In the UI I have one tab per currency.

I want to call a `getLoans()` method to show the loan list within each tab (currency). In the class, I have an array with all the loans and the `getLoans()` method filters that array based on the selected tab (selected currency) and returns the loans filtered.

Below is the code:

```
class MyClass {
    public selectedCurrency: app.models.Currency;
    private loans: app.models.Loan[];

    getLoans(): app.models.Loan[] {
        if (this.loans) {
            return this.loans.filter(this.filterBySelectedCurrency);
        }
        return null;
    }

    filterBySelectedCurrency(loan: app.models.Loan): boolean {
        return loan && this.selectedCurrency && loan.Currency == this.selectedCurrency;
    }
}
```

The above code is not working because in the `filterBySelectedCurrency(..)` method `this.selectedCurrency` is `undefined`. However, debugging the code I see that before calling it (within the `getLoans()` method), `this.selectedCurrency` has the correct value.

Apparently for some reason, I can't access the class variable `this.selectedCurrency` from within the filter method. Is this the case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing in the function directly will cause the context—`this`—to be lost. You can maintain the context by passing in an arrow function instead.

Change this:

```
return this.loans.filter(this.filterBySelectedCurrency);
```

To this:

```
return this.loans.filter((loan) => this.filterBySelectedCurrency(loan));
```